# Fix base long name bar echarts

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, echarts

Have you ever work with echarts? https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-examples/public/index.html
I need a little help.
Anyone knows how to figure out this for the long name in echarts?
[image: ![enter image description here]

This is my code:

```
app.title = 'Long names';

option = {
    tooltip : {
        trigger: 'axis',
        axisPointer : {           
            type : 'shadow'        
        }
    },
    legend: {
        data:['uno','dos','tres']
    },
    grid: {
        left: '3%',
        right: '4%',
        bottom: '3%',
        containLabel: true
    },
    xAxis : [
        {
            type : 'category',
            data : ['fila1 fila fila fila fila fila fila fila fila fila fila fila fial fila fila fila fila fila','fila2','fila3','fila4','fila5','fila6','fila7']
        }
    ],
    yAxis : [
        {
            type : 'value'
        }
    ],
    series : [
        {
            name:'uno',
            type:'bar',
            stack: 'api',
            data:[320, 332, 301, 334, 390, 330, 320]
        },
        {
            name:'dos',
            type:'bar',
            stack: 'api',
            data:[120, 132, 101, 134, 90, 230, 210]
        },
        {
            name:'tres',
            type:'bar',
            stack: 'api',
            data:[220, 182, 191, 234, 290, 330, 310]
        }
    ]
};
```

I don't wanna lose the base name... Anyone know what could I do?
This is the page where I test it:
https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-examples/public/editor.html?c=bar-stack
Thx in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Set interval property to 0 of axisLabel of xAxis

```
xAxis : [
    {
        type : 'category',
        axisLabel: {
            fontSize: 12,
            interval: 0
        },
        data : ['fila1 fila fila fila fila fila fila fila fila fila fila fila fial fila fila fila fila fila','fila2','fila3','fila4','fila5','fila6','fila7']
    }
],
```

Answer (score 1):

Use axisLabel property of xAxis and inside axisLabel use interval property and set it to numeric value.